# Webpack lazily-loaded vendor bundle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm trying to combine the [two-explicit-vendor-trunk](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/two-explicit-vendor-chunks) example with code splitting in webpack. But cannot make it to work.

I have two pages (NOT real pages, it's an SPA using react and react-router):

- / : needs only `vendor.js`
- /d3 : needs both `vendor.js` and `d3.js`

The goal is: when visiting /, only `app.js` and `vendor.js` are loaded. When the user navigates to /d3, `d3.js` is loaded as needed. Here is how I try:

[webpack](https://github.com/kawing-chiu/flask-react-redux-example/blob/4f55c21d856414f555dbd4b7ef76380da2cd5f62/client/webpack_config/common.config.js) [config](https://github.com/kawing-chiu/flask-react-redux-example/blob/4f55c21d856414f555dbd4b7ef76380da2cd5f62/client/webpack_config/webpack.dev.config.js):

```
entry: { 
  vendor: [ 
    'react',
    'react-dom',
    'react-router',
    ...
  ],
  d3: [ 
    'd3',
  ],
  app: [
      './src/js/index',
  ],
},
plugins: [ 
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    minChunks: Infinity,
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'd3',
    minChunks: Infinity,
    async: true,
  }),
  ...
],
```

[Router.jsx](https://github.com/kawing-chiu/flask-react-redux-example/blob/4f55c21d856414f555dbd4b7ef76380da2cd5f62/client/src/js/Router.jsx):

```
export default (
  <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
      ...
      <Route path="d3" getComponent={(location, callback) => {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
          callback(null, require('./pages/D3').default);
        });
      }} />
      ...
  </Router>
);
```

This config doesn't work as expected since the `d3.js` bundle is generated but completely ignored by other bundles. And `d3.js` is also duplicated in chunk `1.1.js`. So how can I make this to work? I need this configuration because d3 is too large and slows down initial loading on home page a lot. Furthermore I need to do long-term caching on both `vendor.js` and `d3.js` so both must be split out as vendor chunks.